# How to generate Java from xsd/wsdl with spring boot 3.x.x in 2023

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, xsd, wsdl

There are couple of projects 1:

```
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

2:

```
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
```

3:

```
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
```

when I compare it plugin from apache is the most 'live' according to mvnrepository but it is not used in projects. First one seems the most recommended but there were 3 years pause according to mvnrepository. And the last one from jvnet which we are currently using with spring boot 2 use some older dependencies. (I don't try it with spring boot 3 )

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <xjbSources>
                    <xjbSource>${basedir}/src/main/resources/mybinding.xjb</xjbSource>
                </xjbSources>
                <sources>
                    <source>${basedir}/src/main/resources/myxsd.xsd</source>
                </sources>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/generated-sources/</outputDirectory>
                <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This plugin was last updated in april 2022, but it produces me source code which contains the `jakarta` package names. I tested some generators, but this one is the first which worked properly.